# Bad ID to Mysql from Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I do something wrong and now rails put bad id value to table.

When app create profile it set for example id 2 but in mysql

```
id = 1
```

Is there some way to fix it? I use devise gem if that helps

Comment: check the user table structure of the id column in the mysql.

Comment: it should set auto increment and increment by 1. Google it you will find this settings.

Comment: uff...fixed...hardcoded but fixed - put 2 empty fields in table and now id == id